# Is it possible to start a new activity with a click of a item in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I was just wondering if I was able to start a new activity with the click of an item inside a ListView.

The code I have written so far:

```
package awad865.project.ContactManager1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.contactmanager1.R;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_contact_listview);
        button1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        button2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_addcontact);
        button3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_options);



        setUpListView();

    }

    private void setUpListView(){
        List <Contact> displayList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        displayList.add(new Contact("Anmol","Wadhwa","53743632"));
        displayList.add(new Contact("Juhi","Goswami","4234232"));
        displayList.add(new Contact("Laurence","Baldwick","243232"));



        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,displayList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

        private Context _context;
        private List<Contact> _contacts;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts){
            super(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);

            _context = context;
            _contacts = contacts;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
            //Create a layout inflater to inflate our xml layout for each item in the list
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //Inflate the list item layout. Keep a reference to the inflated view.
            //No root view specified
            View listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item_layout,null);

            //Access TextView elements inside the view (note we must specify the parent view
            //to look in)
            TextView firstName =  (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_firstname);
            TextView lastName =  (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_lastname);
            TextView number =  (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_number);

            //Set the text for each textview (use the position arugment to find the appropriate element in the list)
            firstName.setText(_contacts.get(position).getFirstName());
            lastName.setText(_contacts.get(position).getLastName());
            number.setText(_contacts.get(position).getNumber());

            return listItemView;
        }

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_groups:
            Intent groupIntent = new Intent(this,Groups.class);
            startActivity(groupIntent);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favourites:
            Intent favouriteIntent = new Intent(this,Favourites.class);
            startActivity(favouriteIntent);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void addContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddContact.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}



class listItemClickedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View clickedView, int clickedViewPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(this, ContactInformation.class);

    }
}
```

I was just wondering if I was able to start a new activity inside the method onItemClick() in the class listItemClickListener. Any help would be appreciated because the compiler doesn't allow me to start a new intent.

Comment: use `onItemClickListener` on listview and post your listener code. `Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactInformation.class)` use activity context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start Activity on ListView item Click as:

**STEP 1:**

Add on OnItemClickListener by passing instace of listItemClickedListener class as:

```
....
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new listItemClickedListener());
```

**STEP 2:**

start Activity from onItemClick as:

```
 Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(clickedView.getContext(), 
                                               ContactInformation.class);
  clickedView.getContext().startActivity(contactInfoIntent);
```

Comment: I tried this but I get a compiler error when I type startActvity(contactInfoIntent)

Comment: Your edited answer didn't give me a compiler error, but when I ran the application and clicked on a item inside the ListView, the application crashed. Do you know what the problem might be ?

Comment: @user123456 : probably you have problem inside getView method. please share log to get more help from us. thanks

Comment: Do I share the LogCat?

Comment: @user123456 : yes please share logcat results for more help

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `Context` you need from `clickedView`.

```
Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(clickedView.getContext(), ContactInformation.class);
clickedView.getContext().startActivity(contactInfoIntent);
```

Comment: How do I start the intent after this?

Comment: When I type in startActivity(contactInfoIntent) I get a compiler error

Comment: Same trick... Of course you can create a local variable for the context.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the click event to each item added to the listView

Answer (score 0):

You could put the Data, in your case ContactDate, as a ContactData element onto your View (each cell) by calling `convertView.setTag(contactData)` in your `getView()` Method.

onItemClick wpuld then do something like this:

```
ContactData cd = (ContactData)clickedView.getTag();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
// put data from cd in that Bundle
Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(this, ContactInformation.class);
startActivity(contactInfoIntent);
```

update:

try this:

```
package awad865.project.ContactManager1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.contactmanager1.R;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView listView;
    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_contact_listview);
        button1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        button2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_addcontact);
        button3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_options);



        setUpListView();

    }

    private void setUpListView(){
        List <Contact> displayList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        displayList.add(new Contact("Anmol","Wadhwa","53743632"));
        displayList.add(new Contact("Juhi","Goswami","4234232"));
        displayList.add(new Contact("Laurence","Baldwick","243232"));



        ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,displayList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

        private Context _context;
        private List<Contact> _contacts;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts){
            super(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);

            _context = context;
            _contacts = contacts;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
            //Create a layout inflater to inflate our xml layout for each item in the list
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //Inflate the list item layout. Keep a reference to the inflated view.
            //No root view specified
            if (convertView == null)
                View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item_layout,null);

            //Access TextView elements inside the view (note we must specify the parent view
            //to look in)
            TextView firstName =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_firstname);
            TextView lastName =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_lastname);
            TextView number =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_number);

            //Set the text for each textview (use the position arugment to find the appropriate element in the list)
            firstName.setText(_contacts.get(position).getFirstName());
            lastName.setText(_contacts.get(position).getLastName());
            number.setText(_contacts.get(position).getNumber());

            //TODO add your data to the View

            convertView.setTag(yourData)


            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_groups:
            Intent groupIntent = new Intent(this,Groups.class);
            startActivity(groupIntent);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favourites:
            Intent favouriteIntent = new Intent(this,Favourites.class);
            startActivity(favouriteIntent);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void addContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddContact.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View clickedView, int clickedViewPosition, long id) {
        ContactData cd = (ContactData)clickedView.getTag();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // TODO put data from cd in that Bundle
        Intent contactInfoIntent = new Intent(this, ContactInformation.class);
        startActivity(contactInfoIntent);

    }
}
```

besides, you usually do iOS development or am i wrong?

Comment: No I have no experience in iOS development and this is the first time I am learning android development

Comment: just guessed because the _context variable. thats objective-c for accessing class variable directly

Comment: I get an error in ContactData cd = (ContactData)clickedView.getTag(), do I have to import something?

Comment: well i assumed you would store your contactInformation in some sort of object, since i dont know how your ContactData looks like i couldnt implement it for you.
ah, just noticed, your class is called Contact, so you will have to change the className. and fill out the todos i left in the code

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

First argument of an `Intent` constructor requires an object of `Context` class. But you supplied an `listItemClickedListener.class`.

Intent constructor requeres:

```
Intent(Context, Class<?>)
```

you supplied:

```
Intent(listItemClickedListener, Class<?>)
```